# Suitable amperage for charging 12V 12Ah DC lead-acid battery

Tags: battery-charging

If I have a 12V 12Ah DC lead acid battery, how to calculate the suitable amperage for the charger? And volt too?

Do I need 12V 2A charger? Or can I use 12V 4A for less charging time? Or this destroys the battery?

I want to know how to calculate this because I have 12V 18A battery too

Comment: It depends on rating or model of battery.  SLA types require accurate controlled voltage with temperature sensing with CC CV and float V control.

Comment: Read the datasheet for your specific battery. Note that at higher charging currents, the life of the battery will probably be reduced.

Comment: What type of SLA? A 70 Ah car battery is regularly charged by the cars' 140 A alternator whereas a 70 Ah leasiure battery will not be happy with more than perhaps 20 A charge current.

Answer (score 1):

For flooded lead-acid batteries, it is generally recommended that you not charge at more than 20 - 25% of the Ampere-hour rating - for your 12 Ah battery, that would be about 3 Amps.  Gell and AGM batteries can often be charged faster than flooded types, but you should check the manufacturer's recommendations.

Comment: To the OP: Charge voltages are somewhat temperature dependent. A lot of good chargers have a temperature sensor or at least a setting (cold, medium, hot). At higher temperatures the voltages need to be a bit lower.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb most manufacturers of Sealed lead acid batteries recommend a max of C/3.It is not so much that higher rates are not possible but if you overcharge at higher currents the battery will out gas. Smart chargers go into a float (stand by) mode when charging is complete. There is one very popular one rated 1.25 Amps that has been around for years that handles these size batteries very well. They make a different charger for gel cell batteries, that have different charging requirements